# Approaches to delete Polygon overlap in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

Is there function to delete the areas of overlap between polygon features to achieve visualized results?

[image]

I'd like to check for each geometry (row) if a geometry **is** intersected, or in other words if a geometry is overlapped by another. If this is the case Id like "erase" the overlap from the other geometry without creating a hole. When there is no direct way to delete the overlap, is it possible to create new features from the overlaps, and then filter them out by a certain size threshold?

Maybe there is a simple way I did not see but please excuse PostGIS is new to me.

Comment: Is this related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363025/how-to-run-a-moving-window-function-in-a-conditional-statement-in-postgis-for-bu ?

Comment: Yes I'd like to know it in general.

Comment: From the picture above, you could split (ST_Split) a polygon p1 with the exterior ring of a polygon p2 if they overlap. So now you have one big polygon p1, one small polygon p1 and the polygon p2: keep only the biggest polygon area grouped by the polygon ID (something like: `.... GROUP BY id HAVING(MAX(ST_AREA(geom))`)

Comment: But how do you know which boundary is the correct boundary ?

Comment: Considering your other questions concerning this issue; what are you going to do with theses buffers? For most tasks other than pure visuals, buffers can (and IMO should) be avoided (e.g. proximity/spatial relation analysis). And for visualizing them, the *rendering application* will usually do a better job at sorting out border issues than an approach on the geometric level. For reference: check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296316/93656) for a (different, but related) visual effect, and note the other answer that has a solution on the geometric level, both in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this and it is good for detecting overlaps

[Check whether table has overlapping polygons, in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243565/check-whether-table-has-overlapping-polygons-in-postgis)

Remove the limit and make it into a table as

```
CREATE Table my.table AS
SELECT *
FROM my_table a
INNER JOIN my_table b ON 
   (a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, '2********'))
WHERE a.ctid != b.ctid
```

The table will potentially have the ids on which you can search and come back to your source table, perhaps modify only on that list of ids.

Answer (score 2):

So, one of the options for solving your problem could be this geo-tool, in the form of SQL-Code.

The input geodata, in the form of a polygonal grid with overlaps of neighboring cells, is shown in Figure 1
[image]

Figure 1

Run the SQL-code:

```
WITH 
tbla AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM poly_grid),
tblb AS (SELECT b.id, ST_Centroid(b.geom) centr_geom, (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom geom FROM tbla a JOIN poly_grid b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblc AS (SELECT a.id, ST_MakeLine(a.geom ORDER BY ST_Azimuth(b.centr_geom, a.geom)) AS geom FROM tblb a CROSS JOIN tblb b GROUP BY a.id, b.id),
line AS (SELECT id, (a.geom) geom FROM tblc a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblb b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.centr_geom, 0.1)))),
poly AS (SELECT id, ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_StartPoint(geom))) AS geom FROM line)   
SELECT id, ST_Union(geom) geom FROM poly GROUP BY id
```

The output geodata, is shown in Figure 2

[image]

Figure 2

Original spatial solutions...

P.S. I hope the mismatch between input and output in your images is just a typo (cell id=4)

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)